# Trying to insert image into database using React and Laravel 7

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I am getting this error in the console:

```
xhr.js:184 POST http://localhost:8000/api/admin 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

This is my component:

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedFile: "",
      banner_img: "",
    };

    this.submitBanner = this.submitBanner.bind(this);
  }

  fileSelect = (event) => {
    this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  submitBanner() {
    let test = this.state.selectedFile;
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("banner_img", this.state.selectedFile);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/admin", test);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Col md={{ span: 10, offset: 1 }} className="mt-4">
        <h3>Banner Image</h3>

        <input
          type="file"
          className="from-control"
          name="banner_img"
          onChange={this.fileSelect}
        />
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.submitBanner}>
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I would start by looking at the server logs to see what is causing the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
<!-- update callback method onclick -->
<Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.submitBanner()}>Submit</Button>  

submitBanner() {
  let test = this.state.selectedFile;
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("banner_img", this.state.selectedFile);
  fd.append("banner_img", fd);
  axios.post("http://localhost:8000/api/admin", fd); // add this line
}
```